# Iterating through pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-analysis

I have a dataframe with following columns:

```
User_id   PQ          TGGS       PAG       Games_played
118399  8.536585    7.079646    10.204082   7.711443
212651  75.000000   73.684211   75.000000   46.534653
210314  60.000000   9.523810    33.333333   14.414414
```

columns are actually game codes. I want to actually recommend a user for a game based on the percentage of the games played by him. In my dataset, the user 212651 has played 75% time PQ game and 73% time TGGS game. So if plays PQ he is likely to play TGGS.  Now this values varies a lot. So the parameter that I have set is 50%. So for a user if a particular game is 50% co related to another game  I want to send him an email stating that next is TGGS game since these two values are highly co-related.

I want to keep the co relation among the values of 50%.
So the code I have written is

```
    for i, num in new_df['PQ'].iteritems():
        if num > new_df['TGGS'] * .5:
            print User_id[num]
            print new_df['TGGS']
```

I am getting an syntax error at line 2.

```
   1467                         "indexers [{key}] of {kind}".format(
   1468                             form=form, klass=type(self), key=key,
-> 1469                             kind=type(key)))
   1470 
   1471     def get_duplicates(self):

TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [8.536585365853659] of <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Can someone give me a good solution for this.

The end goal is to get a datafame with a user_id and if PQ is co related to TGGS True, co related to PAG True. So that I can email that particular user

Comment: Welcome to SO! If any of the answers helped solved your question, it would be beneficial if you close your question by accepting the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select only the items you need in the dataframe with:

```
df[df['PQ'] > (df['TGGs'] * 0.5)]
```